# Could my HF antenna cause problems to these other antennas on the roof?

Tags: antenna, hf, rfi

I am planning to purchase a property soon in an apartment block on the top floor. I am very very keen to install a HF multiband Yagi antenna on the rooftop.

I notice some small cell towers and a vertical antenna on the rooftop already, as shown in the photo below, more than likely for mobile phones?

Just two questions for those with potentially some experience regarding this?

1. Generally, would I be permitted to install a HF antenna such as a hexbeam on the rooftop near these antennas? I would be the owner of the apartment. I realise that this question very much depends on the country, rules, agreements etc.. but in general, as a licensed HAM?
2. Is there a danger of my HF antenna interfering with anything here? or vice-versa.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/19980/will-a-hf-beam-antenna-on-rooftop-building-interfere-with-other-antennas-there

Comment: [Duplicate questions are not allowed](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=Duplicate), sorry.

Comment: You should edit your original question and copy any pictures or other unique info above to it.

Comment: @MikeWaters Agreed. I have edited the original question now and added the photo.